# ExpressJS - populate before save asyc await

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I want to populate user in Feed model, and i cant do that, this is what i tried

```
router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
  const newFeed = new Feed(req.body);
  try {
    const article = await newFeed.populate('created_by');
    const finalArticle = await newFeed.save();

    res.status(200).json({
      success: true,
      message: "Successfully created.",
      data: finalArticle
    })
  } catch (err) {
    next(err)
  }
});
```

Comment: Where does the `Feed` class come from?

Comment: Feed is just a new schema

Comment: What kind of schema? Nothing in your post tells us what kind of db connector or driver you use.) Also, can you please share the implentation of it?

Comment: what do want to achieve by populating ?  and u can not populate a data that is not saved to the databases.